# Can't switch on wireless networking

Tags: 10.10, networking, wireless, ubuntu-netbook

I am having a problem setting up a wireless connection on my linux laptop, does anyone know the shortcut to turn the wireless on, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> on my acer laptop would obviously only apply to the original windows operating system.

Comment: Please add some hardware information to your question, this will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 2):

I would need the model of the laptop. But tipically most wireless problems like yours are solved by installing the drivers.

Go to System > Administration > Additional Drivers and install the Wireless driver that appears there.

Or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type jockey-gtk and install from there (It is the same as the above instruction)

That is, assuming you did not install the proprietary drivers which are the ones found in the additional Drivers window.

Let me know how it went.

Comment: Ahh yes I see now, thank you very much :) I will need to plug an ethernet cable in to download it I presume? xD but yes I believe you've solved it :)

Comment: Before attempting to install drivers (and if you haven't already done this) I recommend clicking on the Network Manager icon in the upper panel. It probably looks like two little screens with a red X or if you are plugged into a wired connection it might look like an Ethernet jack with a cable hovering next to it. If your wireless device is not listed in the drop down menu that results from clicking this icon, and doesn't show up in the output of the 'ifconfig' command, then try installing the drivers.